# Update with $dateToString aggregation causes can't convert from BSON type object to Date in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following document in the database (Mongodb 4.2)

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId(
  "5e58dd49103bba2c961e7d80"
  ),
  "launchProducts": {
    "scheduledLaunchDate": {
      "$date": "2020-02-03T23:00:00.000Z"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to update document and convert existing date object, into formatted string (dd-mm-yyyy) using following functionality of Mongo 4.2 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/

I'm running following query in Mongo Shell:

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, [{"$set": {"launchProducts.scheduledLaunchDate": {"$dateToString": {"date":"$launchProducts.scheduledLaunchDate","format":"%d-%m-%Y"}}}}])
```

Unfortunately I'm getting following error:

```
2020-02-28T11:07:50.375+0100 E  QUERY    [js] WriteError({
    "index" : 0,
    "code" : 16006,
    "errmsg" : "can't convert from BSON type object to Date",
    "op" : {
        "q" : {

        },
        "u" : [
            {
                "$set" : {
                    "launchProducts.scheduledLaunchDate" : {
                        "$dateToString" : {
                            "date" : "$launchProducts.scheduledLaunchDate",
                            "format" : "%d-%m-%Y"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "multi" : true,
        "upsert" : false
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any ideas how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You should never store `Date` as strings, you will just generate problems in future. If you like to get a specific format then you should format the Date value on client side at output.

If you want to get rid of the time part of `scheduledLaunchDate` you can use this pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         "launchProducts.scheduledLaunchDate": {
            $dateFromParts: {
               year: {$year: "$launchProducts.scheduledLaunchDate"},
               month: {$month: "$launchProducts.scheduledLaunchDate"},
               day: {$dayOfMonth: "$launchProducts.scheduledLaunchDate"}               
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that date was stored improperly in MongoDB.

Running `db.collection.insert({"launchProducts": {"scheduledLaunchDate": ISODate("2020-02-03T23:00:00.000Z")}})` first, solved my issue.